# c++ concatenate macro1 text with comma and with macro2

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

From these macros:

```
#define X abc
#define Y def
```

how can I define macro Z the content of which is:

```
abc,def
```

?

I couldn't manage with

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma.hpp>
#define ZZ BOOST_PP_CAT(X,BOOST_PP_COMMA)
```

this produces just:

```
abcBOOST_PP_COMMA
```

Comment: You don't need to concatenate anything, because `,` is a separate token. `#define Z X,Y` should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
X,Y
```

That will do the trick.